# Loop in solving multiple matrix calculation

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, map, infinite-loop

I am wondering is there a way to use loop, like `Do`, `For`, to rewrite the last line in the code. I tried to use `Do` to make this work, but mathematica keeps telling me that "svars will be suppressed during this calculation". I want to do the loop way, not the `Table` way i used below, because `Tabel` gives me a really ugly format of eigenvector.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Remove["Global`*"]

Nmax = 4;

T = 1/2 Sum[m[i] x[i]'[t]^2, {i, 1, Nmax}];
U = 1/2 Sum[k[i] (x[i][t] - x[i - 1][t])^2, {i, 1, Nmax + 1}];
L = T - U;

EL[q_] := D[L, q] - D[D[L, D[q, t]], t]

eigen = Table[EL[x[i][t]], {i, 1, Nmax}];

x[i_][t_] = a[i] E^(I \[Omega] t);

sim = eigen /. t -> 0;
x[0][t] = 0;
x[Nmax + 1][t] = 0;

For[i = 1, i <= Nmax + 1, i++, m[i] = m; k[i] = k; m[5] = 0]

matrix = D[sim, {Array[a, Nmax]}];

Print["\nThe reduced eigenmatrix looks like ", matrix // MatrixForm]

soln = \[Omega] /. Solve[Det[matrix] == 0, \[Omega]];

eigenval = Pick[soln, Resolve[ForAll[{k, m}, k > 0 && m > 0, Positive[#]]] & /@ soln];

Do[Print["\n\nThe positive eigenfrequencies we computed are " \[Omega][i] , " = ", eigenval[[i]]], {i, 4}]

b = Table[a[i], {i, Nmax}];

Table[Solve[matrix.b == 0 /. \[Omega] -> eigenval[[i]], b], {i, 1,Nmax}]
```

Comment: You mean something like `Table[Solve[matrix.b == 0, b], {ω, eigenval}] /. Rule -> Equal // MatrixForm` ?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, but to use the Loop to find the eigenvectors.

Comment: Why "loop"? I think the output is not "ugly" anymore, and `Table` is essentially a loop, too. Or you prefer this format?: `b /. Table[Solve[matrix.b == 0, b], {ω, eigenval}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: Do you know why it won't work whenI change Table to Do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: `Do[Solve[matrix.b == 0, b] /. Rule -> Equal // Transpose // MatrixForm // Print // Quiet, {ω, eigenval}]; Do[b /. Solve[matrix.b == 0, b] // Transpose // Quiet // MatrixForm // Print, {ω, eigenval}]`

Comment: @xzczd So, if you are doing this problem, you will use `Table`? Or you have some other ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll use `Table`, because its output, which is a list of `Rule`, is easy to be used in further calculations together with `ReplaceAll` etc. while there's no way to call those given by `Print` inside `Do`.

Comment: @xzczd I got it, thanks!

Comment: BTW, besides the last line, I believe the entire code can be written in a better way. Maybe you can add some background information for the original problem.

Comment: @xzczd I will be using this form, `Do[b /. Solve[matrix.b == 0, b] // Transpose // Quiet // MatrixForm // Print, {ω, eigenval}]`. Another question, do you know how to `print` "aa[i], eigenvectors" in the same line; namely, "aa1 = first eigenvector","aa2 = second eigenvector". I want it to look nicer.

Comment: `Module[{i = 1}, Do[Print[aa[i] == (b /. Solve[matrix.b == 0, b] // Transpose // Quiet // MatrixForm)]; i++, {ω, eigenval}]]`

Comment: @xzczd I snipped the problem from my homework assignment. Part (3) is what I am asked to do.

Comment: @xzczd Do you know how to change the change the vertical spacing between each `aa[i]` in the output?

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the added information for the original problem, I think your problem can be simply solved by:

```
Clear[k, m]
coe = k/m SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {4, 4}];
efre = Sqrt[-coe // Eigenvalues] // Simplify
evec = coe // Eigenvectors // Simplify
```

If you insist on making the result "look nicer":

```
"The eigenfrequencies are:"
Column[Subscript[ω, #] & /@ Range@4 == efre // Thread, Spacings -> 2]
```

[image]

```
"The eigenvectors are:"
Column[Subscript[v, #] & /@ Range@4 == MatrixForm /@ evec // Thread, Spacings -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great help from you!

Comment: @Lawerance Glad you like it :)

Comment: I took a deep look at your code this afternoon, and came up with several questions. First, it seems `Center` does not have any effect on the alignment of eigenvectors, so why do you put it above? Second, can you explain this to me: `MatrixForm /@ evec // Thread`. So, you `Map` the `MatrixForm` to every `evec`. But when I try `Map[evec]` in the code, I thought it would be the same but I did not work, why?

Comment: @Lawerance `Center` does have no effect here, I just forgot to remove it 囧, edited. For the second question, `Map[evec]` doesn't make any sense, the `FullForm` of `MatrixForm /@ evec` is `Map[MatrixForm, evec]`. also, notice what's `Thread`ed here is `==` i.e. the precedence is `Thread[((Subscript[v, #1] & ) /@ Range[4]) == (MatrixForm /@ evec)]`, you can use `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`.` to check the precedence.

Comment: Thanks! Just got a chance to look at your comments after finishing my midterm yesterday.